# How to connect with Web Api Spotify (in Java)?

Tags: java, rest, api, web-applications, connection

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA.
I'm very beginner so I don't know how to connect with Web Api Spotify.
Please, help me. Teach me step by step with code.

Comment: Do you want to connect via curl via JAVA or ...? Can you specify a little bit more what you want to archive and how. To just connect connect you can execute any endpoint with curl: `curl
https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/1vCWHaC5f2uS3yhpwWbIA6/albums?album_type=SINGLE&offset=20&limit=10`

Comment: I need to create tracks browser via Spotify API. How to start? How to get tracks from this API?

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) as well as [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0):

If you can describe what you wish to do with the API that would help me guide you down the correct path.

To start with most API's need some way to authenticate the caller, spotify here is no exception. To start you must first setup your application as stated in [their documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/quick-start/). Pay extra attention to the "Application Credentials" as these are the values that will allow you to make requests to their API.

Now that you have these credentials you have two options, write your own classes to integrate with the Spotify API or use a external library [like this one](https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-java). Using an external library saves you a lot of time.

From here you will need to read up on the documentation on their [endpoints](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/), calling whichever endpoint you need for your usecase.